# Как восстановить корректную работу базы ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Всем привет!
Есть база на эластике 1.5.0. Общее кол-во данных во всех индексах - 1328134024. Но спустя время, запрос на подсчёт кол-ва показывает`(localhost:9200/_count) - {"count":643792946,"_shards":{"total":35,"successful":35,"failed":0}}`. Как я вижу примерно половина данных потеряна куда-то. Как их восстановить ? Физически размер базы данных не изменился, как был 200гиг так и остался.
Если выполнить запрос - `localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` , видно следующее:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 35,
  "active_shards" : 35,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 35,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : -1
}
```

Т.е. по какой-то причине есть" НЕРАСПРЕДЕЛЕННЫЕ ШАРДЫ".
Подскажите каким образом можно восстановить нормальную работу базы ?
Ранее такая проблема случалась, чтобы её решить, я удалял всю бд и заново восстанавливал её из бэкапа, но это лишь на время помогает. Все параметры эластика по-умолчанию, кроме

```
 curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"transient":{"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "all"}}'
```

Comment: Как вы получили цифру 1328134024?